# Unplugged my USB 3 without safely removing hardware and now my other machine won't read it

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-3, safely-remove-hardware

The title says it all, really! I unplugged my usb 3 drive to take it to my lounge and plug into the media centre and hey presto, it can see the drive, but it shows as an empty folder. Funnily enough it shows up fine with all the files on the initial machine (Windows 8). The media centre is Windows 7.

Any ideas how to get the Windows 7 machine to recognise the drive? It was working before btw.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `chkdsk /r X:`? (X: is the drive letter)

Comment: Unfortunately it now can't see the drive at all :(

Answer (score 0):

In the computer that it works in, try running `CHKDSK` on the drive to fix any file system errors.

To do this:

1. Plug in your USB3 Drive
2. Go to `My Computer`
3. Right click on the drive in question and select `Properties`
4. On the `Tools` tab click on the `Check Now` button
5. Select both options and run

For a preliminary run, you might just want to run it without selecting the two options, it will run faster, but might not fix your problem.

You can also run [CHKDSK from the command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd637756.aspx).

Comment: Ok I just went to my pc and plugged it in and I can no longer read it. ^%$£!

Now what?

Comment: See if you can locate it in Disk Management (`Run -> diskmgmt.msc`), and then right click on it and attempt the steps above starting from 3.

Comment: @MarcoRuschioni - Try a Linux Live CD.  At this point the data likely is corrupt.  Are you sure the files were actually transfered to the drive instead of say shortcuts

Comment: I can't see it in disk management. :(

There was about 500gb on there, of all my media. @Ramhound - what is a Linux Live CD? I don't have a cd drive...

Comment: @Ramhound Ok I see there is a USB Live. I've never touched Linux before, which version should I use, and what exactly must I do once I have booted with LiveUSB? And thanks btw!

Comment: Any version will do, I suggest Ubuntu because of extensive documentation help. See [Installing on USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Comment: @MarcoRuschioni - I was generic on purpose.  I figured you could research and select the Linux Live Environment you wanted to use.

Comment: Thanks, but forgive me - what must I do once I boot with the USB drive? Am I just seeing if I can access the drive, and then copy the contents to another drive? Sorry - newbie.

Comment: Yes, first see if you can salvage your data by copying it off the drive, then attempt to [fix the drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47700/fix-corrupt-ntfs-partition-without-windows) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to restore the drive to a functioning state:

- Insert your broken drive into an USB port.
- Then start an elevated command prompt.

  - Open `C:\Windows\System32\`, right click on `cmd.exe` and "run as administrator"
  - Or, if you have the search box enabled, go to [Start], type `cmd.exe` in the search box. That should show the right file. Right click it and "run as administrator".
- Type `diskpart`
- Type `list disk`. You should get a list of all detected drives, including ones with no valid partitions or damaged filesystems.
- Select the **correct** disk with `select disk X`. (Replace X with the right number).
- Double check that you have the right disk. No typos!
- Use the command `clean` to clear all configuration information and **all information** from the disk. This restores the disk to a known working state.
- Create new partitions as desired. E.g. [`create primary primary`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771243%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to create a new partition.
- Exit diskpart and reformat the new working drive.
- Copy your data from your backup to the USB drive.

[image: Diskpart screenshot.]

Comment: Thanks Hennes. This will be my last resort as I want to see if I can salvage the data on there first.